# configure active directory membership

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory, membership-provider

I want to use membership class and user Active directory as a data source. I have config in web.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="LDAPConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myserver"/>
```

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But when i want to access ASP.net WEB Application Administrator, i have problem like this
"An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again."

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `connectionStringName` should be set to `"LDAPConnectionString"` not to `"ApplicationServices"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (before make sure your connection strings are valid):

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="***ENTER CORRECT NAME OF YOUR CONN STRING" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
         applicationName="/" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>

  </providers>

</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx), not `SqlMembershipProvider`.

The linked MSDN article has an example configuration.